# Azure QnA Maker follow up prompt box size

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker, azure-webapps

I have a Azure Web app bot that uses QnA maker as repository. I have added multiple followup prompts there. But when I integrate the iframe on my website the display of the followup prompts gets cut.How can I resize the followup prompt box so that it fits to the iframe.
[image]

The below screen shot shows..so much of useless space in the followup prompts.How Do I just fit to the text.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B9vS.png)

Comment: It looks like you want two opposite outcomes. First you say you want the buttons to be bigger, and then you say you want the buttons to be smaller. Which is it? Can you explain more about what you're trying to do? Are you using the Bot Framework? Are you using Web Chat? Can you show any of your code?

Comment: My end goal is to reduce the size of the buttons so that is fits in the UI frame in my portal. I did not make any changes to the existing code. I simply used the iframe available from the channel tab and used it in my portal. The first screen shot is from the chat window in my portal.

Comment: While I know what you mean when you say things like "the channel tab" it's a good idea to include links in your question so that more people can get context and possibly help you. In any case, there's never an excuse to not share code. You may have copied the sample iframe element without editing it but you pasted it into an HTML page to get it to render. Not all pages will have the problem you're experiencing, so you need to provide a minimal HTML example so that we can reproduce your problem and try to help you. The bot code that sends the buttons also might be helpful.

Comment: Regarding the Buttons.I have just used QnA maker where I add followup prompts and it comes in the bot as buttons.I have not made any changes to the default bot code. The I have added a screen shot of the UI code

Comment: You should never ever post a screenshot of code. You should always post code as text so that it can be copied (and make sure it's formatted correctly for Stack Overflow Markdown). Please familiarize yourself with this document to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes I am..temporarily I have made changes to the UI width to fit the buttons.This is a temporary walkaround though.I am still not able to make any changes to the button size or the text size.

Comment: Please post a minimal HTML page example so that we can reproduce the problem. Post the actual formatted code as text and not a screenshot. Do not include any secrets or passwords.

Comment: Do you still need help?